# $_GET generates a white flicker

Tags: php, menu

I've got a menu, links within it are sending user to e.g. `?menu=home` but there are many other links. I wanted to use `$_GET[""];` to manage content of website by switch i.e.
`if ($_GET["menu"] == "home")`, everything looks fine, I have background, a website, pictures and stuff, but each time you change `?menu` by clicking on other links than itself, it flickers, for about 0.5 second it is white and then website loads.

Now that wouldn't be a problem if website would be bright like StackExchange, unfortunately my website orbits around dark colors, such flikker throws off the feeling of smoothness on website.

Is there a way to get rid of that white short flicker?

Comment: To clarify, you're seeing the browser clear while the page loads, correct?  If so, please fix your question as I guarantee you that query string or not does not directly impact rendering.  And, why are you concerned with what the browser does between pages?  I strongly recommend focusing on things that are within your control.  There's always AJAX, but it's better to have your content on these pages if it already is.

Comment: So your question is when you click a link to load a page why does the page load? the only way around this is to use frames or ajax to keep the entire page from reloading but instead only the needed parts. This has nothing to do with the use of query variables ir $_GET, so you should probably re-word your question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1):

load your external css file in  section.

set background to html or body element in your css file.

I think your problem is that css is loaded after content so styles are only applied after that and default html and body background is white.